# Connector class dropdown empty in Confluent Control Center?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I have downloaded the confluent platform and then followed the steps given in the confluent quick start page.
I started the confluent platform using cli in standalone mode.
I have installed the  Kafka Connect Datagen etc. using the following command.

```
/bin/confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-datagen:0.1.0
/bin/confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-jms:5.1.2
```

But when I go to the control center and try to add a connector under Kafka Connect, the connector class dropdown is still empty.

[image: Confluent Control Center]

Edit:

Nothing is running on port 8083. However during startup I see everything was started.

```
Starting zookeeper
zookeeper is [UP]
Starting kafka
kafka is [UP]
Starting schema-registry
schema-registry is [UP]
Starting kafka-rest
kafka-rest is [UP]
Starting connect
connect is [UP]
Starting ksql-server
ksql-server is [UP]
Starting control-center
control-center is [UP]
```

Comment: Please show the results of `http://connect-server:8083/connector-plugins`

Comment: @cricket_007 nothing is running on port 8083.  But during startup, I see everything was started.  

Starting zookeeper
zookeeper is [UP]
Starting kafka
kafka is [UP]
Starting schema-registry
schema-registry is [UP]
Starting kafka-rest
kafka-rest is [UP]
Starting connect
connect is [UP]
Starting ksql-server
ksql-server is [UP]
Starting control-center
control-center is [UP]

Comment: Connect REST API is running on some port. The default is 8083.